# How to allow only apt internet access any deny / block everything else

Tags: apt, iptables, firewall

I am building a secure server (Debian with GUI) for offline signing transactions. I don't need internet access. However I would like to have my system automatically update. 
How can I achieve this?

Comment: You'll probably need to set up a local repository, as described [for example here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/170348/how-to-create-a-local-apt-repository)

Comment: Yep. You would need to set up a separate, internet-connected server as a liaison between your secure box and the internet. BTW, you might need to set up your inet restriction in your network hardware, not your secure box itself. A process running as root can always skirt whatever restrictions you have in place locally.

Comment: Here's a possible [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4314473/712526) using `iptables`

Comment: Don't use a DNS server and put the hostname/ip of the mirror you use in /etc/hosts

Comment: running [apt-cacher-ng](http://www.unix-ag.uni-kl.de/~bloch/acng/) on a different host on the LAN is another alternative to having a local repository.  With carefully crafted `iptables` rules, it could even be run in a VM or container on the same host (i.e. allow the VM or container's IP address to make http/https requests, but not the host itself).

Comment: I use apt-cacher-ng in a similar setup, point all the restricted computers to the  apt-cacher-ng server and then iptable allow only the  apt-cacher-ng server internet access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A local repo or repo-cache is needed.

For a local deb mirror:

setup a web server

get [apt-mirror](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=apt-mirror)

configure apt-mirror:

there are three items that should be modified within the apt-mirror config file.

/etc/apt/mirror.lst

point within your web hosted pages.

```
set base_path <somewhere_in_your_web_hosted_page>
```

in my specific instance, amd64 was all that was needed, so to save space I specified.

```
set defaultarch amd64
```

and limit your download rate…
It may be important to limit the download rate in a corporate environment, unless want to negatively impact production applications or sites, trigger the burst rate on your corporate pipe and have a potentially uncomfortable meeting with management about burst rate overage costs.

```
set limit_rate 1m
```

In a security and patch centric environment use at least a two-stage local mirror.  First, move the prior day’s external pull up the chain to the “production” mirror with rsync.  By using rsync, the testing mirror isn’t erased, so apt-miror is only pulling those items that are newly updated, not everything.   After that synchronization, trigger the apt-mirror, against the “testing” mirror.  Less critical servers, update from the testing mirror, to make sure that nothing terrible happened, then the production servers update from the production mirror.

This can all be automated with cron or another type of job manager.